# JPA Bidirectional Relationships vs Repository/DAO-Use

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, repository

i`m struggling myself since a while about this. I have an entity graph with 30 entities. Most of them are connected through bidirectional relationships. Some connections are very useful and some not, because they only serve the convenience in case of deletions between the entities.

Furthermore I have repositories to create/find/store the entities. Unfortunately there is a repository for every entity and it feels like, that these repositories are windows into my object graph. Is such thing a recommended implementation?

Because of the boiler plate code caused by the bidirectional relationships maintaining the parent/child associations I had the idea to replace some of these bidirectional relationships and put this into the repository. Some of these relationships are only useful in conjunction with further parameters. Lets take the classic Customer <-> Order example. I think that the direction Customer -> Order is not always good, because sometimes there is a need to limit the result to a specific period.

My question is: What do you recommend to get out of this struggle? Do you always use bidirectional relationships in bigger projects for the convenience? Or do you replace them with specific repository queries? Is it okay to maintain repositories for every entity?

I'm torn for a while... :-(

Answer (score 0):

Well, in my opinion, it's difficult to say without knowing a little more about your setup. Are you using Spring `CrudRepositories`, custom `Daos` or EntityManager? Perhaps it doesn't make that much of a difference, but I wonder about it.

In short, I was perfectly happy writing an application recently that had 10 or so Enities and only one service layer. Perhaps it can help to think about business needs and start crafting a new service layer. Despite having 30 or so entities, you may only have a handful of business points of view. Customers, obviously, and Orders. Also, probably, Payments, Shipping, Returns.

Look at who is using the application and what do they call their departments. Make a service for that department. Put a call for every need for that department, even if you are duplicating some code from other departments. Don't forget the IT department. Later, when you get a good idea of how these services are shaping up, you can factor out common actions.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. In fact, I have mixed up some things I've learned recently. In the last couple of weeks I started with Domain-Driven-Design. Unfortunately I had problems defining my aggregates, because of performance concerns. For example there is an university with about 400 course of studies. So, the university will be my aggregate root and the course of studies are entities inside it. Every time I need to work with the object it needs to be load from the database and my understandings of performance was irritated. And so I decided to make an aggregate root per entity with a repository.

Comment: But it doesn't felt right, because most entities share a bidirectional relationship and so, you can jump into the graph from every entity (with the help of a repository (incidentally a similar implementation like the Spring version) and navigate to all directions. There are no restrictions and that is the thing that doesn`t feel right. So, I think the DDD-approach is right, but there are already some open questions.

Comment: Design generally has some of the toughest decisions. Thinking of departments as domains can help a lot. The DAO's, or the Entities, really represent just tables. I have often created `View` objects, or DTO's, along with the service layer, unique to each department. That way I have objects that are make sense for the department that uses them.

Comment: My first business application had the same approach I described before (DAO/Repository per Entity). Since I deal with the DDD-thing, my thinking about design has changed but there are still some old patterns which needs to get out of my head.

Comment: By the way, I have a question about the bidirectional relationship (JPA). Usually the relationship needs to be maintained on both sides - parent and child (=owner). If the parent-side is already persisted and I will persist a child with a reference from the parent (setParent) without changing the parent via an addChildToParent, the child will be correctly persisted in the database after leaving the transaction boundary of a StatelessBean. Is it possible that problems occur, because of the unsynchronized collection, which eventually resides in the memory or not?

Comment: Sorry, not sure I really understand that question. Perhaps try a new post?